# Linq Query On IDictionaryEnumerator Possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, caching

I need to clear items from cache that contain a specific string in the key. I have started with the following and thought I might be able to do a linq query

```
var enumerator = HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetEnumerator();
```

But I can't? I was hoping to do something like

```
var enumerator = HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetEnumerator().Key.Contains("subcat");
```

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: aside: enumerating the entire cache is inherently a bad idea on a busy site...

Comment: Yep I hear you all... Back to the drawing board

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Enumerator created by the `Cache` generates `DictionaryEntry` objects.  Furthermore, a `Cache` may have only `string` keys.

Thus, you can write the following:

```
var httpCache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
var toRemove = httpCache.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .Select(de=>(string)de.Key)
    .Where(key=>key.Contains("subcat"))
    .ToArray(); //use .ToArray() to avoid concurrent modification issues.

foreach(var keyToRemove in toRemove)
    httpCache.Remove(keyToRemove);
```

However, this is a potentially slow operation when the cache is large: the cache is not designed to be used like this.  You should ask yourself whether an alternative design isn't possible and preferable.  Why do you need to remove several cache keys at once, and why aren't you grouping cache keys by substring?

Comment: What could be gained by "grouping cache keys by substring"?

Answer (score 5):

Since Cache is an IEnumerable, you can freely apply all LINQ methods you need to it. The only thing you need is to cast it to IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry>:

```
var keysQuery = HttpContext.Current.Cache
    .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .Select(entry => (string)entry.Key)
    .Where(key => key.Contains("subcat"));
```

Now keysQuery is a non-strict collection of all keys starting from "subcat". But if you need to remove such entries from cache the simplest way is to just use foreach statement.

Comment: Would this be a lot more efficient than the below?

Comment: Not sure what is "below", but there hardly exists more efficient solution than a simple foreach.

Comment: No, all solutions posted here are slow in the sense that all must enumerate the entire Cache and examine every key.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a great idea to walk the entire cache *anyway*, but you could do it non-LINQ with something like:

```
    var iter = HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetEnumerator();
    using (iter as IDisposable)
    {
        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            string s;
            if ((s = iter.Key as string) != null && s.Contains("subcat"))
            {
                //... let the magic happen
            }
        }
    }
```

to do it with LINQ you could do something like:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>> ForLinq(this IDictionaryEnumerator iter)
    {
        using (iter as IDisposable)
        {
            while (iter.MoveNext()) yield return new KeyValuePair<object, object>(iter.Key, iter.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

and use like:

```
var items = HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetEnumerator().ForLinq()
       .Where(pair => ((string)pair.Key).Contains("subcat"));
```

Comment: thanks for the above, appreciated - But how would you go about clearing cached items that began with a certain key...?

Comment: by designing such that I don't have to... sorry, not a very good answer I'm afraid

Comment: It's probably the most very reasonable answer possible, however.